# In TVS, is it true that every neighbourhood of zero is sum of some two other neighbourhoods of zero

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a neighbourhood of zero. Is it true that there always exists neighbourhoods of zero A and B such that $V=A+B$?

If this is true, then could it be generalized to neighbourhood of any point, not only zero?

Comment: @J.W. Tanner why no TVS?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/284361/42969.

Comment: @user121882:  maybe you should have specified the context.  I was thinking real numbers, which is a trivial topological vector space

Comment: I assumed that if no context is specified then the widest possible context should be assumed ;)

Comment: $A$ and $B$ with $A + B \subseteq V$ follows from continuity of addition. Exact equality is maybe possible in some cases, not sure. Maybe local convexity helps.

Comment: What exactly does "neighborhood" mean here?  In particular, is a superset of a neighborhood always a neighborhood?